# QFile запись в конец файла

Tags: c++, qt

Как записать в конец файла в Qt C++?

```
QFile file("C:/Dev/log.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    file.write(line);
}
file.close();
```

Так перезаписывает.

Answer (score 4):

По идее так:

```
QFile file("C:/Dev/log.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::Append)) {
   file.write(line);
}
file.close();
```